# How do we set a target in a grunt cssmin task?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I am trying out [cssmin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin) for Grunt

According to the docs targets can be defined "according to the grunt Configuring tasks guide."
When I create a cssmin task using that pattern, like:

```
cssmin: {
  my_target: {
    minify: {
      src: 'path-to/default.css',
      dest: 'path-to/default.min.css'
    }
  }
}
```

the minified file is not created.

If I remove the target level it works as expected.
Do I do something wrong here? or are there other options than cssmin (In my research I picked this as everybody was pointing to it)

Using:

- grunt v0.4.1
- cssmin v0.6.0

Comment: Are you running the task using `grunt cssmin:my_target`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your configuration is just a little off. `minify` is also just a target name. Do this instead:

```
cssmin: {
  minify: {
    src: 'path-to/default.css',
    dest: 'path-to/default.min.css'
  }
}
```

OR

```
cssmin: {
  my_target: {
    src: 'path-to/default.css',
    dest: 'path-to/default.min.css'
  }
}
```

Please read http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks on how to configure tasks.

Comment: Thanks! The second example was what I was looking for. It looks like cssmin uses a slightly different pattern than other Grunt tasks

Comment: All the contrib tasks use `this.files` so you're able to use any of the config patterns listed in the docs: http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks